# add product from codeigniter to magento 2 with options

Tags: magento2, product, configurable-product, custom-options

On my server I have got Magento 2 running and at the same time I have got Codeigniter application.

What I am trying to do, is for my Codeigniter users  to be redirect to my Magento 2 site to complete their transaction from the codeigniter application.

I have created a custom module such to receive call from Codeigniter via Ajax.

In my **`js`** 
I already defined `var productId` and `var SiteUrl`

```
var AjaxUrl=SiteUrl+"/carcomm/index/addproduct/id/"+productId;
```

**Here is my Controller**

```
<?php 
namespace Ray\Carcomm\Controller\Index;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context; 
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;  
class Addproduct extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_cart;
    protected $_productRepositoryInterface;
    protected $_url;
    protected $_responseFactory;
    protected $_logger;


    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResponseFactory $responseFactory,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
        )
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_cart = $cart;
        $this->_productRepositoryInterface = $productRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_responseFactory = $responseFactory;
        $this->_url = $context->getUrl();
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
       $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
       $TotalPrice = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price'); 
       $Product = $this->_productRepositoryInterface->getById($productid);
       //Define options  
       $customOptions = array();    
       $customOptions[0]=array('key' => 1, 'value' =>'Ford', 'title' =>'Car Type');
       $customOptions[1]=array('key' => 2, 'value' => '02-01-2019','title' =>'PickUp Date' );
       $customOptions[2]=array('key' => 3, 'value' => 'Ray Motors','title' =>'Dealer');          
      //::::::::::
        $params = array (
            'product' => $productId,
            'qty' => 1,
            'price' => $TotalPrice,
            'options' =>  $customOptions
        );

       $this->_cart->addProduct($Product, $params);
       $isSaved=$this->_cart->save(); 
       $this->_redirect('checkout/cart/index'); 
    }

}?>
```

Ajax call is working because I logged headers in console and I am getting `200 ok`

However product is not adding and redirection not working.

I am wondering if my approach is not correct or is there any other better approach to achieved this

Comment: If it's an ajax call, then the redirect needs to be triggered by javascript upon ajax completion.

Comment: The code is working by adding the product to the cart but not updating the price and the options on checkout